# Adding point to score

Tags: android

I'm working on a school project in Android Studio (a small game) and I now want to implement scores. 
So here is the code where I want to implement the score:

```
private int score = 0;

final View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.equals(buttonBigger) && doubleResult1 > doubleResult2) {
            Log.v("TAG", "you are right");

            // Add 1 point to score

            generatorEasy1();

            generatorEasy2();
        }

        else {
            Log.v("TAG", "you are wrong");
            goToEndscreen();   // Go to Endacreen when wrong
        }

    }
};
```

So whenever you pressed the right button I want to add 1 point to the score. I've tried the following:

```
if(v.equals(buttonBigger) && doubleResult1 > doubleResult2) {
        Log.v("TAG", "you are right");
        score += 1;
        textScore.setText("Score : " + score);
  }
```

The problem is that if I run the app and I press the right button, the score stays 0.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong so it would be nice if someone could help me.

Comment: Why are you doing v.equals(buttonBigger)? Any reason for that?

Comment: That doesn't matter as the app is running perfectly using that...

Comment: That is the reason your score board is not getting updated. Remove that line and see

Comment: It doesn't work anymore if I remove this line...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to do with this game. But, you can set an on click listener directly on the buttons that are to be clicked. No need to add an if statement to check which view is initiating the listener.

```
biggerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Whatever you want to do when the 
            // button is clicked in here.  
        }
    });
```

Comment: I didn't post the whole code, there are 3 different buttons... and I don't think your answer has something to do with my question...